# Getting Error with Google Analytics API 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hello all I have been working on a Bing Analytics to Google analytics script in python. I have recently figured what was wrong with my goole analytics upload script and after fixing that I have run into a new issue. I keep getting the error There was an API error : 403 : Forbidden . I have looked at all the 403 errors that google has published information about and have corrected everything I thought was wrong and am still getting the error. If someone could help me to figure this out it would be great. Bellow is the code that I am using for my upload script.

```python
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

import csv, os, shutil, glob, datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

home = os.environ["HOME"]
dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%y")


def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service



def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()


  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
    properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=account).execute()

    if properties.get('items'):
      # Get the first property id.
      property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=account,
          webPropertyId=property).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions within the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = 'uploader@bing-ads-analytics.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
  key_file_location = home+'/Desktop/Bing-Ads-Analytics-5684236fdf8e.p12'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))

  try:

    media = MediaFileUpload('Bing_Ad_Upload'+dt+'.csv',
                            mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                            resumable=False)
    daily_upload = service.management().uploads().uploadData(
        accountId='XXXXXXXX',
        webPropertyId='UA-XXXXXXXX-1',
        customDataSourceId='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        media_body=media).execute()


  except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
    print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

  except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
    print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

EDIT!!!
I have fount where the error is occurring. there is something wrong with the daily_upload. could someone please explain to me in better detail than what google gives where to find the accountid, webproprtyid, and customdatasourceid please and thank you.

Comment: Have you done Authorization properly?

Comment: yes because i have the .p12 file that it is asking for in the script am i missing a step on the backend of google analytics or something

Answer (score 0):

You got accountId in:

```
# Get the first Google Analytics account.
account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')
```

And properties in:

```
# Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
  profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
      accountId=account,
      webPropertyId=property).execute()
```